# PHP and jQuery loop throught api call gives me 1 letter at a time

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Big Commerce V3 API using a PHP curl call:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>

<?php

$headers = array(
"Accept: application/json",
"X-Auth-Client:aaaa",
"X-Auth-Token:bbbb" 
);
$chbig = curl_init("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/aaaabbbb/v3/catalog/products"); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($chbig, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $chbig, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$result = curl_exec($chbig);
$http_status =  (string) curl_getinfo($chbig, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($chbig);
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

This gives the correct data, but looks weird: Here is the end result

http://mynew.house/products.php

now I am trying to do an api call via jquery like so:

```
    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://mynew.house/products.php',
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: 'json',
  success: function(result) { 
      $.each(result, function(x, y){
         console.log(x);
         console.log(y);
      });
  }
});
```

and that returns data, but when I loop through it, I only get one letter at a time, why? I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: _but when I loop through it, I only get one letter at a time_ I don't see a loop.

Comment: I had in place, but wanted to see what result looked like again and forgot to change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is giving you back a string. You need to parse it before you can access it like an object.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mynew.house/products.php',
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true
}).success (function(result) { 
  // result is just a string
  console.log (result);
  // convert the response to an actual js object
  // for some bizarre reason this API is returning crap
  // that must be double-parsed??
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse (result));
  console.log (obj);
  obj.data.forEach (function (data) {
    console.log (data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, `forEach` is not a function and actual_javascript_obj still returns string.

Comment: For some bizzarre reason the response from this API seems to require that it be double parsed?